# How to install azuremlsdk for R on rocker/tidyverse:latest?

Tags: r, azure, docker

I try to install `azuremlsdk` for R on `rocker/tidyverse:latest` image:

```
dir.create("library")

install.packages("azuremlsdk", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org", lib="library")
azuremlsdk::install_azureml()
```

However, I get the following error on the last line:

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘azuremlsdk’
>   Calls: :: ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart ->
>   doWithOneRestart

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

P.S. I must install everything inside `library` because otherwise the folder is not writable.

If you can suggest a docker image that includes R and AzureML SDK for R, then I'd appreciate as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-by-step instructions for installing the Azure ML SDK for R:**

**Step1:** Install Conda

If you do not have Conda already installed on your machine, you will first need to install it, since the Azure ML R SDK uses reticulate to bind to the Python SDK. We recommend installing Miniconda, which is a smaller, lightweight version of Anaconda. Choose the 64-bit binary for Python 3.5 or later.

**Step2:** Install the azuremlsdk R package

You will need remotes to install azuremlsdk from the GitHub repo.

```
install.packages('remotes')
```

Then, you can use the install_github function to install the package.

```
remotes::install_cran('azuremlsdk', repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org/')
```

If you are using R installed from CRAN, which comes with 32-bit and 64-bit binaries, you may need to specify the parameter INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch") to only build for the current 64-bit architecture.

```
remotes::install_cran('azuremlsdk', repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org/', INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch"))
```

For more details, refer "[Install the Azure ML SDK for R](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/installation.html)" and "[Azure ML SDK for R](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-sdk-for-r)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.